# Angular Material Input and select inside one form field in single row

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material

I want a material input field and a material select in one line(inside one form field). To get it done I wrote the below code but it goes into two rows. How can I get this input and drop-down in one line?.

Expected result:
[Frontend view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkmY2.png)

My html code :

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-form-field class="p-1">
        <input matInput placeholder="Search table..."
            (keyup)="updateFilter($event)">
            <mat-select name="ampm" [(ngModel)]="selectedtablesearch" (selectionChange)="updateFilter($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let draft_tblselect of draft_tblselects"
                    [value]="draft_tblselect.viewValue">{{draft_tblselect.viewValue}}</mat-option>
               </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need input data list, just give a try as mentioned in the below link: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqqqmgbbomn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted this issue.

Code:

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="mat-elevation-z8"> 
    <div fxFlex="80" class="p-2">
        <mat-form-field class="w-100"> 
            <input matInput placeholder="Search table..." (keyup)="updateFilter($event)">  
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="20" class="p-2"> 
        <mat-form-field class="w-100"> 
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedtablesearch" (selectionChange)="updateFilter($event)"> 
                <mat-option *ngFor="let draft_tblselect of draft_tblselects" 
                    [value]="draft_tblselect.viewValue">{{draft_tblselect.viewValue}}</mat-option>  
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Good to see that you got it... Happy coding

Comment: Hi @denuwanchamara, Did you try adding any bg color for the dropdown field. I have the similar requirement, but when I apply color, the color is appearing as overflowing/spilling beyond the dropdown.